# How to Solve 'Manifest merger failed' error in android-studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-support-library, dex

Error from androidmanifest.xml :

> Execution failed for task **':app:processDebugManifest'** Manifest
>   merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than
>   version 7 declared in library
>   [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0]
>   C:\Users\bsuni\AndroidStudioProjects\Rec\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml
>   Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"
>   to force usage

Comment: you are using some library which require minimum sdk to be 7 and you are giving 1 as minimum sdk

Comment: Keep minSdkVersion 7 in your app/build.gradle file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I have regenerate this error :**

You have selected **minSdkVersion to 1** while you created project.

as well as you are using :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

*due to this error occurs.*

**suggestion by android-studio :**

```
use android.support.v7.appcompat
```

**solution :** change in gradle

```
minSdkVersion 7
```

Comment: *suggestion by android-studio :

use android.support.v7.appcompat* ... **lol** ... sugestion is: `use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.2'
        }
    }
}
```

}

NOTE :Add this to your build.gradle and **make sure** you are using the same versions as '26.0.2'.