# Manifest merger failed arror in android

Tags: android, manifest-merging

I'm very new to programming. After adding Google Maps Activity I am getting this error with my manifest file. I've tried everything I could but its proving difficult.

thanks in advance

**here [my android manifest file](https://pastebin.com/jRGGnJQE)**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763700/how-to-solve-manifest-merger-failed-error-in-android-studio

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':ParseStarterProject:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of gradle try using location google service `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1`and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1`instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'`